# Why does not display the attribute html via xpath php

Tags: php, xpath

Why does not display the attribute html via xpath php

```
<?php
$content = '<div class="keep-me">Keep this div</div><div class="remove-me" id="test">Remove this div</div>';
$badClasses = array('');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xPath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($badClasses as $badClass){
$domNodeList = $xPath->query('//div[@class="remove-me"]/@id');

$domElemsToRemove = ''; // container of deleted elements
foreach ( $domNodeList as $domElement ) {
    $domElemsToRemove .= $dom->saveHTML($domElement); // concat them
    $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement); // then remove
}

}

$content = $dom->saveHTML();
echo htmlentities($domElemsToRemove);
?>
```

> Works - //div[@class="remove-me"] or //div[@class="remove-me"]/text()
>
> Not working - //div[@class="remove-me"]/@id

Maybe there is a way easier

Comment: Please post your code here, not in a 3rd party website.

Comment: My confusion is that if you just want the value - why are you then trying to delete the element from the document?

Comment: I just don't know php well, I found this code on the Internet how to make it better and easier?

Comment: I think an important part of using code off the internet is actually understanding what it is doing rather than just copying it.

Comment: Many different codes were looking for from them only this one worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath `//div[@class="remove-me"]/@id` is correct, but you need to just loop over the returned elements and add the `nodeValue` to a list of matching ID's...

```
$xPath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$domNodeList = $xPath->query('//div[@class="remove-me"]/@id');

$ids = []; // container of deleted elements
foreach ( $domNodeList as $domElement ) {
    $ids[] = $domElement->nodeValue;
}

print_r($ids);
```

Comment: I need to get the id value, ie 'test'

Comment: I think, and it really is not clear, is that he/she wishes to retrieve the ID of the div with class `test`

Comment: Why does this code not want to work together with wordpress 4.9.8 and in a separate file.php it works because of what could be?
https://prnt.sc/lwz34z
https://prnt.sc/lwz4dr

Comment: It may be better to put this as a new question with the code you are using, the page your trying to run this on so that others may be able to help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to fetch the ID of any element with class `"remove-me"` as is how I interpret the question then perhaps you can try like this - untested btw...

.... other code before

```
$xp=new DOMXpath( $dom );
$col= $xp->query( '*[@class="remove-me"]' );
if( $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach($col as $node){
        $id=$node->hasAttribute('id') ? $node->getAttribute('id') : 'banana';
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

however looking at the code in the question suggests that you wish to delete nodes - in which case build an array of nodes ( nodelist )  and iterate through it from the end to the front - ie: backwards...

Comment: I need to get the value of the attribute 'id' (test)